# React native, passing events from TabBarIOS through Navigator IOS

Tags: navigation, react-native

I have a react project which on the index.ios it has a navigator that looks like so..

```
          <TabBarIOS>

        <TabBarIOS.Item 
          title="example List" 
          selected={this.state.selectedTab === "example"}
          icon={require("./App/assets/sassiListIcon.png")}
          onPress={this.sassiHandleChange.bind(this)} >
          <View style={styles.main}>
            <example></example>
          </View>
        </TabBarIOS.Item>

        <TabBarIOS.Item 
          title="partners" 
          selected={this.state.selectedTab === "partners"}
          icon={require("./App/assets/partnersIcon.png")}
          onPress={this.partnersHandleChange.bind(this)} >
          <View style={styles.main}>
            <NavigatePartners></NavigatePartners>
          </View>
        </TabBarIOS.Item>

        <TabBarIOS.Item 
          title="About" 
          selected={this.state.selectedTab === "about"}
          icon={require("./App/assets/aboutIcon.png")}
          onPress={this.aboutHandleChange.bind(this)} >
          <View style={styles.main}>
            <About></About>
          </View>
        </TabBarIOS.Item>

      </TabBarIOS>
```

In the Partners tab it takes you to a NavigatorIOS which looks like so...

```
        return (
        <NavigatorIOS
      style={styles.mainContainer}
      initialRoute={{
        title: 'Partners',
        component: Partners,
        backButtonTitle: 'Back',
      }}/>

        )
```

Which then takes you to a page called partners and then to a page called partner.

Now when the Navigator is pressed, if the page is on partner, I want it to go back to Partners, but how do I register an even from the tab page and send it to the partner page?
Thanks so much as always

Answer (score 2):

To pass a function from the Partners to the partner page ( a parent to a child ), you can do this the same way you pass any other property down, as a prop. When you are using the Navigator, you have to make sure you assign the passProps property to the navigator.

For example, if you had a function called alertClick, here is how you would pass it to another component with a navigator:

```
alertClick() {
    alert('clicked')
  },

  _handlePress() {
    this.props.navigator.push({
      id: 2,
      passProps: {
        alertClick: this.alertClick
      }
    });
  },
```

So, if you wanted to pass a function all the way down from the TabBar to the bottom child component, you could do it like so:

```
alertClick() {
  alert('clicked')
}

<TabBarIOS.Item 
      title="partners" 
      selected={this.state.selectedTab === "partners"}
      icon={require("./App/assets/partnersIcon.png")}
      onPress={this.partnersHandleChange.bind(this)} >
    <View style={styles.main}>
      <NavigatePartners alertClick={this.alertClick}></NavigatePartners>
    </View>
</TabBarIOS.Item>

// Then, in Partners

_handlePress() {
  this.props.navigator.push({
    id: 2,
    passProps: {
      alertClick: this.props.alertClick
    }
  });
},

// Then, in partner

<TouchableHighlight onPress={ this.props.alertClick } >
```

I've set up a full working example with the passProps assigned to the navigator and the function being passed down as well, without the TabBar [here](https://rnplay.org/apps/wKX_Dw). Code is also below.

https://rnplay.org/apps/wKX_Dw

```
'use strict';
var React = require('react-native');
var {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  Navigator,
  TouchableOpacity,
  TouchableHighlight
} = React;

var SCREEN_WIDTH = require('Dimensions').get('window').width;
var BaseConfig = Navigator.SceneConfigs.FloatFromRight;

var CustomLeftToRightGesture = Object.assign({}, BaseConfig.gestures.pop, {
  // Make it snap back really quickly after canceling pop
  snapVelocity: 8,
  // Make it so we can drag anywhere on the screen
  edgeHitWidth: SCREEN_WIDTH,
});

var CustomSceneConfig = Object.assign({}, BaseConfig, {
  // A very tighly wound spring will make this transition fast
  springTension: 100,
  springFriction: 1,
  // Use our custom gesture defined above
  gestures: {
    pop: CustomLeftToRightGesture,
  }
});

var PageOne = React.createClass({

  alertClick() {
    alert('clicked')
  },

  _handlePress() {
    this.props.navigator.push({
      id: 2,
      passProps: {
        alertClick: this.alertClick
      }
    });
  },

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={[styles.container, {backgroundColor: 'green'}]}>
        <Text style={styles.welcome}>Greetings!</Text>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={this._handlePress}>
          <View style={{paddingVertical: 10, paddingHorizontal: 20, backgroundColor: 'black'}}>
            <Text style={styles.welcome}>Go to page two</Text>
          </View>
        </TouchableOpacity>
       </View>
    )
  },
});

var PageTwo = React.createClass({
  _handlePress() {
    this.props.navigator.pop();
  },

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={[styles.container, {backgroundColor: 'purple'}]}>
        <Text style={styles.welcome}>This is page two!</Text>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={this._handlePress}>
          <View style={{paddingVertical: 10, paddingHorizontal: 20, backgroundColor: 'black'}}>
            <Text style={styles.welcome}>Go back</Text>
          </View>
            <TouchableHighlight underlayColor="orange" onPress={ this.props.alertClick } style={{ paddingLeft:10, paddingRight:10, height:60, flexDirection: 'row', alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center', backgroundColor: 'orange', marginTop:20 }}>
                    <View>
                <Text style={{fontSize: 14}}>Function from parent</Text>
                      <Text style={{ fontSize: 22 }}>Click for alert</Text>
              </View>
            </TouchableHighlight>
        </TouchableOpacity>
       </View>
    )
  },
});

var SampleApp = React.createClass({
  _renderScene(route, navigator) {
    if (route.id === 1) {
      return React.createElement(PageOne, Object.assign({navigator}, {...route.passProps}))
    } else if (route.id === 2) {
      return React.createElement(PageTwo, Object.assign({navigator}, {...route.passProps}))
    }
  },

  _configureScene(route) {
    return CustomSceneConfig;
  },

  render() {
    return (
      <Navigator
        initialRoute={{id: 1, }}
        renderScene={this._renderScene}
        configureScene={this._configureScene} />
    );
  }
});

var styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
  },
  welcome: {
    fontSize: 20,
    textAlign: 'center',
    margin: 10,
    color: 'white',
  },
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('SampleApp', () => SampleApp);

module.exports = SampleApp;
```

Comment: Your example doesnt really solve my problem though.  I know how to pass props through the navigator, my problem is what happens if the person is already on the partner page and they press the tab at the bottom of the page, then I need to send that alert down the children but not through the navigator as we are already on the bottom child we are not still navigating through